# Empty string statement is not working correct with NIB file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I setup a NIB file with 3 textfields. I want to check if the fields are empty. If not do something.

I am using a delegate pattern for checking if the field is edited:

```
@IBAction func didEditingText(_ sender: UITextField) {

    if self.textInputOne.text != "" {
        delegate?.formIsFilled(delegateCalled: true)
    } else {
        delegate?.formIsFilled(delegateCalled: false)
    }

}
```

This function is linked to each field. When it's not empty anymore, it will activate a button. But, when I leave the field blank, it will still make the button active. As I know, my if statement is checking if the text input is not an empty String, but the delegate in my other VC is still be called. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you tell me what control event is connected to that function? Also, how did you implement the delegate method? Also, do you want the buttons to be activated when any one of the text fields is filled, or when all of the text fields are filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the if's condition you are only checking one of the three fields (`self.textInputOne.text != ""`). As the three fields are wired to the same function, you need to change the condition so it is as follows:

```
@IBAction func didEditingText(_ sender: UITextField) {

    if sender.text != "" { // You can use !sender.text.isEmpty too
        delegate?.formIsFilled(delegateCalled: true)
    } else {
        delegate?.formIsFilled(delegateCalled: false)
    }
}
```

This way, when you finish editing a field, the function will check if that field is empty or not and call your delegate.

Comment: ... or even just `delegate?.formIsFilled(delegateCalled: sender.text.isEmpty)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have several textfields it will be better to check all them in the same time / function:

```
func validation() -> Bool {
    for tf in [textFieldFirst, textFieldSecond, textFieldThird] {
        guard let text = tf?.text, !text.isEmpty else { return false }
    }
    return true
}
```

Previously described function you can call inside `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    button.isEnabled = validation()
}
```

You can check your validation in the `viewDidLoad()` or after view initialization:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button.isEnabled = validation()
}
```

Project example you can check [in the link](https://github.com/sergVn/Test-TextFieldValidation).

As a result after correct validation you can call delegate method with any result.